# Origin error with google hangouts

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

New to google hangouts, and after it's going well through the G+ samples I started on a hangout app. 
I moved my gadgets and js into google-code svn and refrenced the API.

When I run my app through the developer window, it loads my XML & JS but has a problem referencing the API: 
I receive -

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load /channel/test">https://plus.google.com/hangouts//channel/test..."
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I swapped my xml out for the example @ https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-hangout-samples/source/browse/simple-app/simpleHangoutApp.xml -but I still receive the error.

I know its a crossdomain issue, but I am just wary that I have missed something fundamental in the setup as it seems weird if this would always be the case they don't mention it in the docs.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out?  I'm running into the same issue.  I followed the steps in the very first part of a tutorial and I'm getting this same exact error on my reference to rpc.js from `https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com`.  My script tag is the following:`<script src="//hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/apps/gadgets/js/rpc.js"></script>`